# How do we create Sub Site using JavaScript object module

Tags: 2013, client-object-model

My using following script to create Sub site.

```
<script 
    src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js" <br/>
    type="text/javascript"><br/>
</script><br/>
<script<br/>
    type="text/javascript" <br/>
    src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"><br/>
</script><br/>
<script <br/>
    type="text/javascript" <br/>
    src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"><br/>
</script><br/>

<script type="text/javascript"><br/>
function myFunction()<br/>
{<br/>
alert('started');<br/>

var siteUrl = " ";<br/>

//get client context and root web<br/>
//var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();<br/>
//var rootWeb = clientContext.site.rootWeb();<br/>
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);<br/>
var rootWeb = clientContext.site.rootWeb();<br/>
this.clientContext.load(rootWeb);<br/>
this.clientContext.executeQuery();<br/>

//set creation info<br/>
var WCI = new SP.WebCreationInformation();<br/>
WCI.set_webTemplate('sts#0');<br/>
WCI.set_description('Created Using CSOM');<br/>
WCI.set_title('Custom SubSite');<br/>
WCI.set_url(url);<br/>
WCI.set_useSamePermissionsAsParentSite(true);<br/>
WCI.set_language(1033);<br/>
this.rootWeb.get_webs().add(WCI);<br/>
this.rootWeb.update();<br/>

// save site and set callbacks<br/>
this.clientContext.load(this.rootWeb);<br/>
this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(<br/>
Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnSiteCreationSuccess),<br/>
Function.createDelegate(this, this.Error));<br/>
}<br/>
</script><br/>

<p>Click the button to trigger a function.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

</div>
```

My Facing following error.

- What url is undefined [WCI.set_url(url);]
- Script are not getting loaded MicrosoftAjax.js,sp.runtime.js and sp.js
- This script i have added inside script viewer web part SharePoint 2013.

Kindly provide me proper approach to create subsite using javascript object module.

Comment: Are you looking for JSOM or CSOM?

Comment: Unable to get property 'get_webs' of undefined or null reference" any idea

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For JSOM Something like this would work...however you need to request full trust for your app.

```
function createWebsite() {

var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext('your url');
this.oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();

var webCreationInfo = new SP.WebCreationInformation();
webCreationInfo.set_title('My New Web Site');
webCreationInfo.set_description('Description of new Web site...');
webCreationInfo.set_language(1033);
webCreationInfo.set_url('MyNewWebSite');
webCreationInfo.set_useSamePermissionsAsParentSite(true);
webCreationInfo.set_webTemplate('mall');

oWebsite.get_webs().add(webCreationInfo);
oWebsite.update();

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}
```

You can load the JS files in the default.aspx page like this in the PlaceholderMain.

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink5" name="sp.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink6" name="sp.runtime.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink7" name="sp.core.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
```

and i tend to add the ajax in the head.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
```

S

Comment: what should i put in place of "MyNewWebSite" webCreationInfo.set_url('MyNewWebSite');

Comment: whatever you want to call it...no spaces

Comment: it worked like charm.

Comment: Great stuff. Vote it up! ;-)

Comment: Worked for mee too ! I put the `JS Files` references in the master page because I am not able to modify the `default.aspx`. Is that normal ? But I have a problem with the site tempalte. How can I apply a customized site template i already created (Available as `Solution`) ? When I put its name in `webCreationInfo.set_webTemplate('MyTemplate');` I got an error (Invalid arguments for the site template) ...

Comment: Have You resolved with creating from custom Template?

Comment: @GennadyG, Please find my answer to create subsite using Custom tempate..

Comment: Thank You SID! I used this example to do this task: http://nikcharlebois.com/create-new-site-from-custom-web-template-in-office-365-sharepoint-online/

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with REST API but be careful with user permission.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "/_api/web/webinfos/add",
        type: "POST",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        data: JSON.stringify({
            'parameters': {
                '__metadata': {
                    'type': 'SP.WebInfoCreationInformation'
                },
                'Url': <New SubSite URL>,
                'Title': <New SubSite Title>,
                'Description': 'Test',
                'Language': 1033,
                'WebTemplate': 'sts',
                'UseUniquePermissions': true
            }
        })           
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Custom Template:

```
function CreateWebsite(title, description, webUrl, templateTitle)
{    
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    context.load(web);
    var webTemplates = web.getAvailableWebTemplates(1033,false);
    context.load(webTemplates);
    context.executeQueryAsync(function(){
            var enumerator = webTemplates.getEnumerator();
            var customTemplate;
            while(enumerator.moveNext())
            {
                var webTemplate = enumerator.get_current();
                var webTitle = webTemplate.get_title();
                if(webTitle == templateTitle) // templateTitle = Custom Tempalte Title
                {
                    customTemplate = webTemplate.get_name();
                    break;
                }
            }                
            var webCreationInformation = new SP.WebCreationInformation();
            webCreationInformation.set_title(title);
            webCreationInformation.set_description(description);
            webCreationInformation.set_language(1033);
            webCreationInformation.set_url(webUrl);
            webCreationInformation.set_useSamePermissionsAsParentSite(true);
            webCreationInformation.set_webTemplate(customTemplate);
            web.get_webs().add(webCreationInformation);
            context.executeQueryAsync(function(){
                alert('Website created successfully.');
            }, 
            function(sender, args){ 
                alert(args.get_message());
                });
        }, 
        function(sender, args){ 
            alert(args.get_message())
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
set_webTemplate("[guid-id feature]#MyTemplate")
```

ex.

```
set_webTemplate("{4a110786-9683-4734-97ca-f2eca95ca377}#MyTemplate");
```